# Kill window or application just like linux do

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, kill

Is there any way to kill or force closed a particular hanging window or hanging application by selecting it with some hotkey?  Similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and select window in Ubuntu?

(I may be misremembering the exact key shortcut used in Ubuntu; I just remember some key combination does that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this utility [xkill](http://windows.xkill.free.fr/download.html) and modified one [here](http://solo-dev.deviantart.com/art/Windows-xKill-100737525). It might help some people who needs it like me:)

Answer (score 9):

Ctrl+Shift+ESC to show Task Manager, on the Processes tab, right-click the offending process and choose "End Process"

Personally I replace Task Manager with Process Explorer (from [sysinternals](http://www.sysinternals.com/)), better list navigation and you can use the Del key to kill a process.

Comment: Task Manager accepts the Del key too.

Comment: I think downvote for 'Task Manager', it sucks but upvote for Process Explorer; it's full of win. So, you just get this comment. :-).

Comment: How do I know which of those process is my window?

Answer (score 3):

Alt-F4 or click the close button. If the app doesn't respond within a few seconds, Windows XP (and probably everything after that) will show a dialog where you can kill it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use tskill.exe from run menu or command prompt.

```
TSKILL processid | processname [/SERVER:servername] [/ID:sessionid | /A] [/V]

  processid           Process ID for the process to be terminated.
  processname         Process name to be terminated.
  /SERVER:servername  Server containing processID (default is current).
                         /ID or /A must be specified when using processname
                         and /SERVER
  /ID:sessionid       End process running under the specified session.
  /A                  End process running under ALL sessions.
  /V                  Display information about actions being performed.
```

Comment: This answer is more to the point. :-).