# Cannot kill process in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Killing an unresponsive process](https://superuser.com/questions/125293/killing-an-unresponsive-process)

I'm running Windows 7 x64. Once in a while I have a process that freezes and that cannot be killed. I've tried the following:

1. Process Explorer
2. pskill
3. taskkill /F /T

Nothing worked. Tools report that the process was killed successfully, but it just stays there.

How do I kill it?

Comment: What's the name of the process?

Comment: It doesn't matter. This happens to different processes. It's just a third party application. It's not a system process.

Comment: You used: Taskkill /pid PID# /F /T ?

Comment: Crosspost in http://serverfault.com/questions/185794/cannot-kill-process-in-windows-7

Comment: Did you try [xkill](http://windows.xkill.free.fr/download.html) ?

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: No. I didn't. Does it work differently compared to the tools I used? Unfortunately I have rebooted my computer already, so I can only try it next time some app freezes.

Comment: @r0ca: Sure. Otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: According to the accepted answer for [Kill window or application just like linux do](http://superuser.com/questions/66176/kill-window-or-application-just-like-linux-do/66603#66603), it seems to work in a different manner. Please drop a line here if you can find a chance to try it.

Comment: When you started "process explorer" did you ensure it was started in Administrator Mode? Some processes, however, cannot be killed at all. That is because they become hooked into the kernel somehow (most often due as a result of some debugging mode) and thus even the administrator cannot release it from the system.

Comment: Also note that if the program was successfully killed but is being re-created then it is possible that a "watcher" process is re-starting the process if it detects that the watched process died. Check the "process id" of the process you're about to kill. When you see it again does it have a different "process id"?

Comment: @PP: Sure. I've tried each tool in the admin mode. No. It's not recreated. It has the same PID. It just won't close.

Comment: Reboot...;-)...